# how to add category to blog project django

Tags: django, django-models, foreign-keys

i developed a blog project by watching many open-source courses and create my own django custom admin dashboard where i want to add a category option to my blog project, i have watched some tutorial on as well but couldn't find them helpful

> models.py

```
from django.db import models

from django.forms import ModelForm
from farmingwave.models import BaseHeader,Submenu

class Category(models.Model):
    mainmenu=models.ForeignKey(BaseHeader,null=True,on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    submenu=models.ForeignKey(Submenu,on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class AdSideMenu(models.Model):
    title_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    title_name = models.TextField()
    url = models.TextField()
    priority = models.IntegerField()
    submenu_status = models.TextField()

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'admin_side'

class CreateBlog(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    blog_Title = models.TextField(max_length=100)
    content = models.TextField(max_length=5000)
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category,null=True,on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    class Meta:
        db_table = 'create_blog'
```

> they are inhereting data from another app
> models.py

```
`class BaseHeader(models.Model):
    main_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    title_name = models.TextField()
    url = models.TextField()
    priority = models.IntegerField()
    submenu_status = models.TextField("false")

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'base_header'
      
class Submenu(models.Model):
    sub_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    main_id = models.IntegerField()
    sub_name = models.TextField()
    url = models.TextField()
    priority = models.IntegerField()
    mainmenu=models.ForeignKey(BaseHeader,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    class meta:
        db_table = 'base_subheader'`
```

and the view function:

```
def create_blog(request):
    if request.method =='POST':
        form = CreateBlogForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            form = CreateBlogForm()
    else:
        form = CreateBlogForm()
    base = BaseHeader.objects.all()
    sub =  Submenu.objects.all()
    create = CreateBlog.objects.all()
    category = Category.objects.all()
    context = {
        'form' : form,
        'createblog' : create,
        'category' : category,
        'menu' : base,
        'sub_menu' : sub,
```

Comment: I don't understand what exactly you are trying to achieve. You already have added a category field to CreateBlog right? What is the problem you are facing?

Comment: i actually want to achieve chained dropdown to create blog acoordingly

Answer (score 0):

Why not make the category a select item?

```
CATEGORY_CHOICES = (
    ('sports', 'sports'),
    ('tech', 'tech'),
    ('politics', 'politics')
)
category = models.CharField(max_length=100, choices=CATEGORY_CHOICES, blank=False)
```

You'd be able to access it like any other field now, so let's say the user clicked on "Politics articles" you can add a .filter(category="politics") and access it in the templates through {{ article.category }}

I don't know why there are all of these lines in your code, nor do I know the scale of your project, but that's how I would go about doing it.